# Why does my Docker container not return control to the terminal after starting?

Tags: python, bash, shell, docker, dockerfile

I have a shell script that I use to export Env variables. This script calls a python script to get certain values from a web service that I need to store before running my primary python script.

I've tried using a `RUN . /bot/env/setenv.sh`, but this doesn't seem to make the env variables available in the final container. I've tried putting the contents in an `entrypoint.sh` file that ends in calling `python jbot.py`, but the container never completes its setup (I assume because the script inside the entrypoint is a continuous loop?)

My `entrypoint.sh` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
. /jirabot/env/setenv.sh
python jbot.py
```

And the `setenv.sh` is just:

```
#!/bin/bash
export SLACK_BOT_TOKEN="xoxb-token"
export BOT_ID=`python env/print_bot_id.py ${SLACK_BOT_TOKEN}`
```

My full Dockerfile is:

```
FROM python:2

COPY jirabot/ /jirabot/
RUN pip install slackclient schedule jira
WORKDIR /jirabot
#CMD [ "python", "jbot.py" ]
ENTRYPOINT [ "/jirabot/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

When I do `docker run bot`, I can verify that the application is running (the bot responds to my requests appropriately). However, all of the `print()` statements within `jbot.py` are absent from the output -- so I have two primary questions:

1. Why does my `entrypoint.sh` just hang the container from returning? I do `docker run bot`, and I'm never returned control of the terminal. However, the bot seems to startup fine.
2. Why do I not get any of my print statements from `jbot.py` when I open a second terminal and do `docker logs <container>`?

fwiw, my `jbot.py` is a `while True:` loop, monitoring for input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. You are not running the docker container [as a daemon](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached--d).

> docker run -d bot

2. In my experience, print messages don't make it to the logs without input buffering disabled in python.

> python -u jbot.py

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, you should check the documentation of `docker run`. Shortly, you are attaching with container so you will never return to your terminal. In order to detach, you need to add option `-d`.

The common used command to launch a container is `docker run -idt <container>`.

For your second question, the information is not enough to identify the problem, sorry. Maybe you can try again after you launching a container properly.